# How to fix "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference at java.io.StringReader"?

Tags: java, android

When I run the app it starts successfully but after sometime it crashes and show this error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>           Process: com.tregix.serviceprovider, PID: 16455
>           java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
>               at java.io.StringReader.(StringReader.java:50)
>               at android.text.HtmlToSpannedConverter.convert(Html.java:758)
>               at android.text.Html.fromHtml(Html.java:245)
>               at android.text.Html.fromHtml(Html.java:188)
>               at com.tregix.serviceprovider.adapters.CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter.java:44)
>               at com.tregix.serviceprovider.adapters.CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter.java:24)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6673)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6714)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5647)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5913)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)

My code is given below

```
    public class CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        private final List<Category> mValues;
        private final OnListInteractionListener mListener;

        public CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Category> items,
                                           OnListInteractionListener listener) {
            mValues = items;
            mListener = listener;
        }

        @Override
        public CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.category_item, parent, false);
            return new CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
            holder.mCategoryView.setText(Html.fromHtml(mValues.get(position).getTitle()));

            if(mValues.get(position).getSubCategories() != null &&
                    !mValues.get(position).getSubCategories().isEmpty() ) {
                String subTitle = Constants.EMPTY_STRING;
                for(SubCategory subCategory : mValues.get(position).getSubCategories()){
                    subTitle = subTitle.concat(subCategory.getTitle()+ ", ");
                }
                if ( !subTitle.isEmpty() && subTitle.charAt(subTitle.length() - 2) == ',') {
                    subTitle = subTitle.substring(0, subTitle.length() - 2);
                }

               holder.description.setText(subTitle);

            }

            Picasso.with(holder.mThumb.getContext()).load("http:"+mValues.get(position).getCategoryImage().
                    getUrl()).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(holder.mThumb);


            holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (null != mListener) {
                        // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
                        // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
                        mListener.onCategoryListInteraction(holder.mItem);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mValues.size();
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public final View mView;
            public final TextView mCategoryView;
            public final TextView description;
            public final ImageView mThumb;
            public Category mItem;

            public ViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                mView = view;
                mCategoryView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cateogry_title);
                description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cateogry_desc);
                mThumb =  view.findViewById(R.id.cateogry_icon);

            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return super.toString() + " '" + description.getText() + "'";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think that your `mValues.get(position).getTitle()` which you pass into `Html.fromHtml` is null

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

you are checking if subtitle is empty :

```
if ( !subTitle.isEmpty() && subTitle.charAt(subTitle.length() - 2) == ',') {
                    subTitle = subTitle.substring(0, subTitle.length() - 2);
                }
```

but error suggests that in some cases it is null, which you didn't check for:

```
if ( subTitle!= null && !subTitle.isEmpty() && subTitle.charAt(subTitle.length() - 2) == ',') {
        subTitle = subTitle.substring(0, subTitle.length() - 2);
}
```

Comment: but it shows error on com.tregix.serviceprovider.adapters.CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter.java:44) at com.tregix.serviceprovider.adapters.CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter.java:24) at

Comment: did you try my solution? is it still crashing?